# GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks error compile time

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-client

should I use google drive bat I can't compile this activity

```
package com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * An abstract activity that handles authorization and connection to the Drive
 * services.
 */
public abstract class BaseDemoActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
...
```

I use Google Plugin for Eclipse to install the library and google APIs
but since compile error

```
GoogleApiClient cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: How have you included the GoogleApiClient library? Is it a jar that you have added to the project? Are your imports correct? Are you missing `import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;`?

Comment: mmm not, how to import on my project. it does the plugin automatically?

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img849/3487/o5zq.png  photo my project

Comment: http://imageshack.com/a/img33/9447/7rpk.png photo my lib

Comment: yes but not compile see screenshoot

Comment: Go to the "Order and Export" tab of your project build path (the last screenshot) and make sure that the Google stuff is checked, then apply the settings. That may fix it.

Comment: done http://imageshack.com/a/img833/4656/ftk9.png not work :-(

Comment: It looks like the com.google.android.gms package is part of the Google Play Services SDK. I found a tutorial on how to set it up. Perhaps it could help you: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html . Make sure that you follow the instructions for Eclipse and not for Android Studio.

Comment: I followed the guide but it does not work

Comment: I really can't help you without you providing more information about where things are going wrong.

Comment: I do not know what information to provide. 
if you want to do other screenshots. 
the problem and that does not compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the [Google+ Platform Quickstart for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android) in order to install Google Play Services as a *library project*.

In particular see step 5:

```
5. Import the Google Play Services library project.

    Select File > Import > Android > Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
    Select Browse.... Enter <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/.
    Select google-play-services_lib. Click Finish to import.
```